# Bizarre image loading problem from apache2

Tags: images, apache2, gzip

Users have complained a few times about seeing a bizarre set of pink or green stripes on our webpage. At first I thought there were a rash of video card outages, but then someone sent me a screenshot from their browser (IE8). I later saw the same thing, but with slightly different colors on Chrome. Users have experienced this on their iPads and iPhones (iOS Safari). Because I've optimized the site to cache images, the bad image stays around until you clear your cache, so once you do, it resolves itself. My assumption is that the transmission of the image is being cut off mid-stream and then staying that way, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here's what I've checked:

Header length is being sent, and transmission looks okay (wget sample below):

```
wget http://www.superiorlivestock.com/templates/sla2/images/wallbg2.jpg
--2012-04-05 08:46:00--  http://www.superiorlivestock.com/templates/sla2/images/wallbg2.jpg
Resolving www.superiorlivestock.com (www.superiorlivestock.com)... [ip redacted]
Connecting to www.superiorlivestock.com (www.superiorlivestock.com)|[ip redacted]|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 45926 (45K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: `wallbg2.jpg'
```

Images are not being served gzipped (apache conf below):

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

The site is www.superiorlivestock.com, and here's a sample of the bad page load:
[image: Screenshot]

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Am I saving my images in the wrong format somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I noticed when I looked at your page in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is that some of your images (specifically [this one](http://www.superiorlivestock.com/images/superior-spring-for%20buyers.jpg), which toomanyairmiles already posted a screenshot of, and [this other one](http://www.superiorlivestock.com/images/next%20stop%20auction%20block%20logo%202012.jpg)) are simply **huge** — the first one is 4.2 *megabytes!*

When I first loaded the page, the huge image was corrupted, more or less like in toomanyairmiles's screenshot.  When I reloaded the image, it downloaded correctly.  However, curiously, in both cases the image file I got was 4,362,346 bytes long; it's just that, in the broken version, after 3,903,489 bytes the correct image data stopped and was replaced by something else (which, alas, looked just like random bytes — or compressed JPEG image data — in a hex editor).

Anyway, I suspect that resaving those few huge images at a more reasonable size should at least make the problem occur much less frequently, even if it won't actually fix the underlying cause of the data corruption.  As a bonus, your website will also load faster.

Comment: Son of a... we have a system in place for the users to create thumbnails of the images, which they consistently forget to use.

Comment: Ah, users. :)  You might want to consider if there's any way of making the thumbnail generation happen automatically, then.

Comment: The best part is that the person who is supplying the images sometimes give them to us with an embedded ICC profile that's corrupted. So ultimately, there are problems all over the process stream. Thanks for the heads up, I made the classic mistake of assuming a user problem was "fixed" and moved on.

Comment: I've gone back through and audited all those images, entire homepage loads in about 636kb now, 58k after initial image caching.

Comment: I haven't gotten any complaints since we changed that so that may have been the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're not the only one having such problems, look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/96460/apache-returns-truncated-image) and [here](http://drupal.org/node/57081), there are some suggestions on fixes in these threads - have you ruled these out already?

Are you in a multi web server environment? Could one of the servers in the pool have a corrupted copy of the image?

Interestingly it's not limited to the background image, and the corruption affects the downloaded image which suggests there might indeed be a problem with the file rather than the server - how are you saving the images?

[image]

Comment: This is all being served up from one VMware VM which runs Debian 6 (Squeeze). 
We are saving the images for web using the settings specified in this screenshot : http://www.superiorlivestock.com/settings.png
Is that the problem, should they be saved as progressive?

Comment: @NateDSaint those settings look ok, what is the resolution set to, how do you upload the files to the server?

Comment: Resolution is whatever it needs to be for that image, we save for web so we don't have final pixels per inch, we just save to whatever the pixel amount is. (in my example above, 465x700). We get files to the server in a variety of ways, including FTP and dropping files into a samba share. The bizarre thing is that the images don't always load this way, if you refresh, it tends to fix itself, and we are only using one data store.

Comment: @NateDSaint Yes, I see what you mean, it is very odd indeed - did any of the ideas in those other threads help?

Comment: I can potentially try the suggestion at the first one, but 1) I'm not sure how to test it, I'm having a hard time reproducing this and 2) they warn it'll impact performance. The second link seems to refer to problems during php image upload, and a majority of these files are dropped directly to the server.

Comment: @NateDSaint I agree it's tricky, you may be better of on server fault with this one as they have more Apache nerds than we do...

Comment: Makes sense, I wasn't sure where this should go as it was a visual glitch. I'll try over there. Is there a way to just migrate the question or should I just ask again?

Comment: @NateDSaint I've flagged it for migration, it's just a case of waiting for the admins to catch up.

Comment: @NateDSaint No problem, I hope you find an answer.

Comment: I think it was a problem of giant files on the home page. The one you have in the image above was one of them. This seems to have fixed it. Thanks for looking into it for me!